How to correctly type the return values?
I created a custom ofetch instance inside a Nuxt 3 Plugin and I am exposing a wrapper function like this:
   const api = $fetch.create({ // ... });

    return {
        provide: {
            api
        },
    };

This is how I use it:
const downloadFile = async (url: string, method: 'GET' | 'POST', params: any | null, filename?: string) => {
    const options = params
        ? ({ method, body: JSON.stringify(params), responseType: 'arrayBuffer' } as NitroFetchOptions<any>)
        : ({ method, responseType: 'arrayBuffer' } as NitroFetchOptions<any>);
    const response = await $api.raw(url, options);
    const type = response._data.type ?? response.headers?.get('content-type'); // Error here on response type
};

Now the response type is inferred to FetchResponse<?>. How can I fix this?
I can call .$fetch.raw<any> and the warning goes away. But it does not feel right.
